# Using type inheritance for a handler function in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

Assume I have this code:

```
import { Telegraf } from "telegraf";
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN || "");

bot.on(message("text"), async (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.message?.text);
});
```

Here, the `ctx` parameter has an long and strange type that gives me lots of props accessible.

Now, I want to change it to have a handler function without using the type `AnStrangeType`:

```
async function handleMessage(ctx: AnStrangeType): Promise<void> {
  console.log(ctx.message?.text);
}
bot.on(message("text"), handleMessage);
```

is there any way to have something like type inheritance for the arguments of the handler function?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Telegraf } from "telegraf";
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN || "");

bot.on('message', async (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.message?.text);
});

// pick the selected generic call.
// You may need `<typeof message("text")>` generic here, I dunno what's `message` function
type call = typeof bot.on<'message'>
// 2nd arg is the function you are looking for
type arg = Parameters<call>[1]
// make a variable of that type
const handleMessage: arg = async (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.message?.text);
}
```